# Uncaught TypeError: firstArray.join is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to coding and javascript in general. I've been trying to make a calculator to get myself more familiar with the language, and just for fun. I'm running into a problem, I can type my numbers in and use all my math operators just fine. What ever result you get will be made equal to my firstArray so that the user can add,subtract,multiply,divide with the last number they have on screen. I get the error that in the title, and I don't get what not working and why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Template</title>

  <style>
    h1 {
      color: salmon;
      text-align: center;
      border-bottom: solid;
      background-color: white;
    }
    body {
      background-color: rgb(0, 209, 243);
    }
    #zero {
      position: relative;
      left: 0px;
    }
    #clear {
      position: relative;
      left: 0px;
    }
    #keypad {
      background-color: salmon;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    #results {
      background-color: white;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 2px;
      width: 96px;
      margin: auto;
      height: 20px;
    }
    #calculator {
      border: solid gray 4px;
      width: 100px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    #screen_1 {
      text-align: left;
      margin: auto;
      overflow-Y: hidden;
      overflow-X: hidden;
      text-overflow: hidden;
    }
    #math {
      width: 100px;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Number!</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="results">
      <p id="screen_1"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="keypad">
      <button id="one" class="button">1</button>
      <button id="two" class="button">2</button>
      <button id="three" class="button">3</button>
      <br>
      <button id="four" class="button">4</button>
      <button id="five" class="button">5</button>
      <button id="six" class="button">6</button>
      <br>
      <button id="seven" class="button">7</button>
      <button id="eight" class="button">8</button>
      <button id="nine" class="button">9</button>
      <br>
      <button id="clear" class="button">C</button>
      <button id="zero" class="button">0</button>
      <button id="equal" class="button">=</button>
    </div>
    <div id="math">
      <button id="plus" class="button">+</button>
      <button id="minus" class="button">-</button>
      <button id="multiply" class="button">*</button>
      <button id="divide" class="button">/</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var firstArray = new Array;
    var secondArray = new Array;

    var next = false;

    var plusBoolean = false;
    var minusBoolean = false;
    var multiBoolean = false;
    var divideBoolean = false;

    var x = document.getElementById("screen_1");


    document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("1");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("1");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("2");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("2");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("3");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("3");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("four").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("4");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("4");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("five").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("5");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("5");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("six").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("6");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("6");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("seven").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("7");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("7");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("eight").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("8");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("8");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("nine").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("9");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("9");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("zero").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("0");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("0");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })

     document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function() {
      next = true;
      plusBoolean = true;
      x.innerHTML = "";
    })
     document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function() {
      next = true;
      minusBoolean = true;
      x.innerHTML = "";
    })
     document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", function() {
      next = true;
      multiBoolean = true;
      x.innerHTML = "";
    })
     document.getElementById("divide").addEventListener("click", function() {
      next = true;
      divideBoolean = true;
      x.innerHTML = "";
    })
     document.getElementById("equal").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (plusBoolean == true) {
        firstArray = Number(firstArray.join("")) + Number(secondArray.join(""));
        x.innerHTML = firstArray;
        secondArray = [];
        console.log(firstArray);
      } else if (minusBoolean == true) {
        firstArray = Number(firstArray.join("")) - Number(secondArray.join(""));
        x.innerHTML = firstArray;
        secondArray = [];
        console.log(firstArray);
      } else if (multiBoolean == true) {
        firstArray = Number(firstArray.join("")) * Number(secondArray.join(""));
        x.innerHTML = firstArray;
        secondArray = [];
        console.log(firstArray);
      } else if (divideBoolean == true) {
        firstArray = Number(firstArray.join("")) / Number(secondArray.join(""));
        x.innerHTML = firstArray;
        secondArray = [];
        console.log(firstArray);
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function() {
      firstArray = [];
      secondArray = [];

      next = false;
      plusBoolean = false;
      minusBoolean = false;
      multiBoolean = false;
      divideBoolean = false;
      x.innerHTML = "";
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In what line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes inside `equal` click listener.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Template</title>

  <style>
    h1 {
      color: salmon;
      text-align: center;
      border-bottom: solid;
      background-color: white;
    }
    body {
      background-color: rgb(0, 209, 243);
    }
    #zero {
      position: relative;
      left: 0px;
    }
    #clear {
      position: relative;
      left: 0px;
    }
    #keypad {
      background-color: salmon;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    #results {
      background-color: white;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 2px;
      width: 96px;
      margin: auto;
      height: 20px;
    }
    #calculator {
      border: solid gray 4px;
      width: 100px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    #screen_1 {
      text-align: left;
      margin: auto;
      overflow-Y: hidden;
      overflow-X: hidden;
      text-overflow: hidden;
    }
    #math {
      width: 100px;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Number!</h1>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="results">
      <p id="screen_1"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="keypad">
      <button id="one" class="button">1</button>
      <button id="two" class="button">2</button>
      <button id="three" class="button">3</button>
      <br>
      <button id="four" class="button">4</button>
      <button id="five" class="button">5</button>
      <button id="six" class="button">6</button>
      <br>
      <button id="seven" class="button">7</button>
      <button id="eight" class="button">8</button>
      <button id="nine" class="button">9</button>
      <br>
      <button id="clear" class="button">C</button>
      <button id="zero" class="button">0</button>
      <button id="equal" class="button">=</button>
    </div>
    <div id="math">
      <button id="plus" class="button">+</button>
      <button id="minus" class="button">-</button>
      <button id="multiply" class="button">*</button>
      <button id="divide" class="button">/</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var firstArray = new Array;
    var secondArray = new Array;

    var next = false;

    var plusBoolean = false;
    var minusBoolean = false;
    var multiBoolean = false;
    var divideBoolean = false;

    var x = document.getElementById("screen_1");


    document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("1");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("1");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("2");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("2");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("3");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("3");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("four").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("4");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("4");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("five").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("5");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("5");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("six").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("6");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("6");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("seven").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("7");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("7");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("eight").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("8");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("8");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("nine").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("9");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("9");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("zero").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (next == false) {
        firstArray.push("0");
        x.innerHTML = firstArray.join("");
      } else if (next == true) {
        secondArray.push("0");
        x.innerHTML = secondArray.join("");
      }
    })

     document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function() {
      next = true;
      plusBoolean = true;
      x.innerHTML = "";
    })
     document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function() {
      next = true;
      minusBoolean = true;
      x.innerHTML = "";
    })
     document.getElementById("multiply").addEventListener("click", function() {
      next = true;
      multiBoolean = true;
      x.innerHTML = "";
    })
     document.getElementById("divide").addEventListener("click", function() {
      next = true;
      divideBoolean = true;
      x.innerHTML = "";
    })
     document.getElementById("equal").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (plusBoolean == true) {
        firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) + Number(secondArray.join(""))];
        x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
        secondArray = [];
        console.log(firstArray[0]);
      } else if (minusBoolean == true) {
        firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) - Number(secondArray.join(""))];
        x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
        secondArray = [];
        console.log(firstArray[0]);
      } else if (multiBoolean == true) {
        firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) * Number(secondArray.join(""))];
        x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
        secondArray = [];
        console.log(firstArray[0]);
      } else if (divideBoolean == true) {
        firstArray = [Number(firstArray.join("")) / Number(secondArray.join(""))];
        x.innerHTML = firstArray[0];
        secondArray = [];
        console.log(firstArray[0]);
      }
    })
     document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function() {
      firstArray = [];
      secondArray = [];

      next = false;
      plusBoolean = false;
      minusBoolean = false;
      multiBoolean = false;
      divideBoolean = false;
      x.innerHTML = "";
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Once you join an array, you cannot push to it again. Joining an array in your case, turns it into a string.